# Maximum allowed size of HELLO in AODV

Tags: ns2

I am working with AODV in ns2.

In my work i want to add some information which is dynamic in nature (size is not fixed) to the "Hello" of AODV. **But I am not able to find how to check what is the maximum size of information that can be attached to the "Hello"?**

Kindly give your valuable suggestions regarding the same.

Regards
Ranjana

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no fixed size for hello packets. But the fixed hello interval in ns2 is 1000 ms. also You can change the interval time.